# Why is the object on the scene null?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object named "Diam" on the scene. Why the first if is triggered and not else. After all, Diam is on the stage, it should not be equal to zero?
P.S. Okay, let it be null. Question: What did we check then?

```
public class CircleCode : MonoBehaviour{
    public GameObject Diam;

    void Start() {
        if (Diam == null){
            Debug.Log("Diam == null");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Diam is not null");
        }
    }
}
```

[It's my objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB9Fn.jpg)

Comment: Having an object in the scene and having a reference to it assigned to a variable on a different object are two different things. You either need to assign the reference to `Diam` in the inspector or find a particular object in the scene and assign it. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html could help in the latter case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `CircleCode` and Drag Diam game-object on `Diam` field in inspector.

Comment: Yes, everything worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned Diam in the Inspector?

Comment: No, I don't know what does mean "assigned" and how I can do this